# Adding a library with the notation ext: 'aar' or @aar doesn't import the transitive dependencies

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, android-library

I've white labeled an app by converting my app into a library and I have a configuration file which is passed to the library to change colours, add a new loading animation, change some text, etc. The library has all those dependencies listed above. When I import the library into the new app, since the new app is just a variation of the library, it won't compile unless I import these dependencies as well.

I added the custom library using:

`compile(group: 'com.lib.libcore', name: 'libcore', version: '1.0.35', ext: 'aar', classifier: '')`

in the `build.grdle` but it still forces me to include all the dependencies from the library.

I was wondering if anyone knows why I need to include all the dependencies from my custom library in my app.

So I have these dependencies:

```
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.5.0'
compile ('com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.4.2')
compile ('com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.4.2')
compile ('com.google.firebase:firebase-crash:11.4.2')
compile ('com.google.firebase:firebase-invites:11.4.2')
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.4.2'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:11.4.2'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.4.2'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.4.2'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:11.4.2'
```

When I import the library using gradle, I need to include all these dependencies in the app gradle file as well. Does anyone know how I can remove it from the app gradle without the app failing?

Comment: what library are you talking about?

Comment: @Raghunandan essentially I've white labeled an app by converting my app into a library and I have a configuration file which is passed to the library to change colours, add a new loading animation, change some text, etc. The library has all those dependencies listed above. When I import the library into the new app, since the new app is just a variation of the library, it won't compile unless I import these dependencies as well. I'm trying to figure out how not to have to import the dependencies twice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It happens because you are using the notation `ext: 'aar'`

```
 compile(group: 'com.lib.libcore', name: 'libcore', version: '1.0.35', ext: 'aar', classifier: '')
```

It is the same of:

```
compile('com.lib.libcore:libcore:1.0.35@aar')
```

You can check the [official doc:](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/dependency_management.html#ssub:artifact_dependencies)

> An artifact only notation creates a module dependency which downloads only the artifact file with the specified extension. Existing module descriptors are ignored.

It means that **you want to download only the aar artifact, and no dependencies.**

Just remove the notation `ext: 'aar'` or the `@aar` in your dependency.

Comment: I'm getting a failed to resolve error now when i try to synchronize the gradle

Comment: What is the exact error message? Since you are using the firebase libraries v.11.4.2 you have to use the add the maven google repo.

Comment: Error:(136, 13) Failed to resolve: com. lib. libcore: libcore:1.0.35

Comment: @Mikerizzo I just use **your** comment below to indicate the library. I don't know if it exists. My answer just explains why you have to add the dependencies nested in the library (and you can avoid it). And it is related to all dependencies. But I can't know if the library that you are trying to add exists or requires a custom repo to be downloaded.

Comment: Thanks. I realized that the path is messed up.

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti, I'm having the exact same issue as the OP. I published a library / SDK as an AAR file to include resources, and therefore none of the dependencies get recognized when trying to use it. What do you mean by "you can avoid it?" Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use custom library in your project you have to add it as dependency in your **build.gradle** **(Module:app)**

Comment: I added the custom library using     compile(group: 'com.lib.libcore', name: 'libcore', version: '1.0.35', ext: 'aar', classifier: '') in the build.grdle but it still forces me to include all the dependencies from the library

Comment: I think you should add all the dependencies from the library to use it